# How can I fetch firestore documents by the Id of an item in it's sub array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

First of all sorry if the title is not very explicit (I don't speak English very well).

I have a Firebase firestore collection. In this collection all the documents have an array.

Here is an example of how the documents are structured:

- Document

  - Id
  - Array

    - Item1

      - Item1Id
    - Item2

      - Item2Id

I have the Id of an item of the array (e.g. 'Item1Id') and I want to fetch all the documents in which the array contains an item with this Id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. This page explains how to perform queries on Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

`array-contains` will return documents that have an array containing the `itemId`, but it doesn't work with nested data.

A solution would be to create an `itemIds` array in your document that simply contains the list of itemIds, and perform the query on that field.